# How to scale Android game image assets when my base design is 135x240 px?

Tags: android, pixel, screen-size, display

I develop mobile game for Android and my base design is 135x240 pixels. The game itself is pixel art.

How I should multiply core design to get images with the appropriate resolution for the most popular mobile displays?

I know there is standard different screen pixel densities (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi), but I cannot understand how this will work for my case. Also my game is only in portrait orientation.

Answer (score 1):

Consider your base design as `mdpi` image, and create others according to the following list:

- (0.75x) for low-density
- (1.0x baseline) for medium-density
- (1.5x) for high-density
- (2.0x) for extra-high-density
- (3.0x) for extra-extra-high-density
- (4.0x) for extra-extra-extra-high-density

Comment: Thank you for explanation, but here is design example for one of my interface elements: http://i.imgur.com/u7K77mi.jpg And there is a problem when I multiplay x1.5 my base design.

Comment: Then create your images for `xxxhdpi` and scale them down for other densities.

Comment: I need new design for (1.5x) for high-density.